# Linq to select latest records

Tags: c#, linq

I have the data structure

[image]

For each item there is a record of it's price on a certain date in each currency.  I need to create a query that returns the most current price for each currency.

This query works, but returns multiple `Amounts` for currency ID `1`.  It should only return 3 records, `7,8 and 9` as these represent the most up to date prices in all currencies for this item.

```
var q = (from c in db.tblStoreItemPrices where c.ItemID == ID select new { c.CurrencyID, c.Amount });
```

Please ignore all ordering and assume that records are randomly ordered.

Comment: "assume that records are randomly ordered"

Would it not make more sense to have a clustered index other than the primary key in order to reduce this random'ness for performance alone.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.tblStoreItemPrices
    .Where(c => c.ItemID == ID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.CurrencyID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).First())
    .Select(c => new { c.CurrencyID, c.Amount });
```

Explanation:

1. Select rows for the specific ItemID
2. Group by CurrencyID
3. From within each currency group select the row that has the most recent date (leaving one row for for each CurrencyID in the result set)
4. Pull out the information you want from these rows

Comment: Thanks - this was a great help. In ASP.NET MVC 5 it was just problem with First - after changed to FirstOrDefault it was working great. Thanks again :)

Comment: rather then orderByDescending based on date,do orderByDescending on id, because id most probably indexed and associated with latest data , so the query will be fast.