# Returning Most Recent Records Based on Serial Number

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following model

```
public class EngineComplianceMetric
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Complied { get; set; }
}
```

`SerialNumber` isn't unique to the table, as the same item could have been repaired multiple times over the years.

I'm trying to return a list that only includes each Serial Numbers most recent record that's before some set date.

So far I have

```
previousCompliedList = _dbContext.ComplianceMetrics
                                 .Where(e => e.BuildDate < startDate)
                                 .Distinct().ToList();
```

But this is just returning everything prior to the `startDate`.

Comment: [check for this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026772/linq-to-select-latest-records)  or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761070/select-most-recent-records-using-linq-to-entities). Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group your items by serial numbers, then you have to take the most recent item in each group (by ordering them and taking the first).

```
previousCompliedList = _dbContext.ComplianceMetrics
      .Where(cm => cm.BuildDate < startDate).ToList()
      .GroupBy(cm => cm.SerialNumber)
      .Select(cm => cm.OrderByDescending(c => c.BuildDate).First());
```

Based on your error, you have to add the .ToList() after the where (before the GroupBy). But doing this will fetch all the items from the DB where the date is smaller and then run additional manipulations on it in memory.

If you don't want to fetch all the items from the DB, you will have to implement a solution similar to Astrid's suggestion in the comments.

I would recommend googling your error messages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60874316/7175057

Comment: I get the below error with that
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: e.EngineSerialNumber,
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
    EntityType: EngineComplianceMetric
    ValueBufferExpression:
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
    .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.BuildDate)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: I tried adding the .ToList() to the end of it but still got the same issue

Comment: I suppose this won't be any more successful regarding EF Core, but just in case: What if you try replacing the `.Select( )` with `.Select(cm => cm.MaxBy(c => c.BuildDate)).ToList()`?

Comment: You have to add the .ToList() after the where (before the GroupBy). But doing this will fetch all the items from the DB where the date is smaller and then run additional manipulations on it in memory. I updated the answer